# suppose we have a polynomial function such that

Tags: polynomials, roots

is it possible that for x=a and x=b (a, b are real), there exists exactly one root in the interval [a,b] if f(a)*f(b) > 0? what are the possible results if function is discontinuous?

Comment: If f is continuous and f(a)*f(b) > 0 the, f must cross the axis y==0 an even number of times between a and b. If it discontinuous, you can say nothing.

Comment: All polynomial functions are continuous.

Comment: Possible, so long as the root has even multiplicity.